# In reversi, can you overwrite two chips in one move?

Tags: othello

In [Reversi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi) if you have a line of chips `--xxxy--`, you can place another `x` in the 5th position and overwrite the `y` you for sure *can* get the line `--xxxxx-` (where x is light, y is dark, and - is empty, line may be horizontal, vertical or main diagonal).

Can you do the same if the line contains one (or more) enemy chip in between? If you for example have `-xxyxyx-`, can you get `-xxxxxxx`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. From the [Rules of Play](https://www.mastersofgames.com/rules/reversi-othello-rules.htm):

1. > Each piece played must be laid adjacent to an opponent's piece
2. > so that the opponent's piece or a row of opponent's pieces is flanked by the new piece and another piece of the player's colour.
3. > All of the opponent's pieces between these two pieces are 'captured' and turned over to match the player's colour.

where I have split up and numbered the clauses of the paragraph for easier reference.

Note that:

- from (1), the suggested move is illegal, not being adjacent to an opposing piece;
- even if one is playing to make `-xxyxy--` into `-xxyxyx-`, by (3) only the second 'y' is flipped, resulting in `-xxyxxx-` upon completion of the move; and
- playing to make `-xxxyy--` into `-xxxyyx-` **does** convert multiple opposing counters, by (2) and (3), flipping to yield `-xxxxxx-` upon completion of the move.

  **Reason:**

  "All of the opponent's pieces between the these two pieces *[(the just placed piece and the enabling friendly piece at the far end of the just surrounded enemy row of pieces)]* are 'captured' and turned over to match the player's colour."

Comment: What about a case like `XYY-YYX` where an X is played in the center? Ignoring for the moment whether such a board scenario is possible, I would think that it would flip all the Ys as two separate lines can be drawn from the move coordinate: one to the left and one to the right. If not, what is the precedence when this is generalized to 2 dimensions? Say you have a move that would draw a line up and down-right, for example.

Comment: My expectation was correct